# ATAPI Incompatible, no DVD ROM detection

Tags: troubleshooting, dvd, optical-drive

I have bought a computer, but I do not know how to properly identify the DVD ROM drive. 
I have tried all the IDE configurations:
 SATA primary, PATA secondary, etc., but it always gives me the error "Secondary Master Drive - ATAPI Incompatible".

So I can not boot any installation DVD. The BIOS is an American Megatrends v02.61.

Comment: What is your motherboard brand/model & dvd drive brand/model?

Comment: @Darth Android
motherboard:Biostar intel g31
dvd:super writemaster speedplus

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall this issue when you are not using an appropriate cable or when the cable is bad.  Try a new cable and if that doesn't work, try an 80 wire cable.

For the difference between an 80 wire cable and a 40 wire cable reference:
http://www.mikeshardware.com/howtos/howto_connect_ide_hd.html

Comment: I red about cable/jumper problems but I cannot open the case or I would void my guaranty. So I am hoping it is a bios misconfiguration.
Thanks for your answer, though.